# Call of overload function is ambiguous while using function template in codeblocks

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
void swap(T & x, T & y){
    T temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}



int main(){
   char ch1,ch2;
   cin>>ch1>>ch2;
   swap(ch1,ch2);
   cout<<ch1<<" "<<ch2<<endl;
   int a,b;
   cin>>a>>b;
   swap(a,b);
   cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

here is the source code...i don't know whats getting wrong over here.I followed call by reference.But every time i tried to run the code, code Blocks gave me ambiguous error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the error and line number.  Also swap is a function in the std namespace.  Remove the line `using namespace std;` and try again. Or call your template something other than `swap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
template<class T>
void swap(T &x, T &y){
    T temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main(){
   char ch1,ch2;
   std::cin>>ch1>>ch2;
   swap(ch1,ch2);
   std::cout<<ch1<<" "<<ch2<<"\n";
   int a,b;
   std::cin>>a>>b;
   swap(a,b);
   std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<"\n";
   return 0; 
}
```

Since swap is already present in namespace, you would not be able to overload it when using namespace std.

Comment: yeah, it worked. so is it more preferable to use( std::) instead of( using namespace std)?

Comment: I suppose you are writing your own swap() for learning purposes. You could just put swap in a separate namespace or change the name to myswap.

Comment: Its not the preference or anything, it is just that swap is present in the namespace called std. If u had changed _swap_ to something other than _swap_, say _swap1_ or _Swap_, **using namespace std** wouldnt have mattered.
(Note that it is Capital S in Swap.)